# Pass django model query as json response

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a social network. I want to load the comments of each post so I make an API call to the server to fetch all the comments of the required posts. The code will make everything clear:

**urls.py**

```
path("comments/<int:post_id>", views.load_comments)
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

**views.py**

```
def load_comments(request, post_id):
    """Returns the comments to index.js"""

    try:
        # Filter comments returned based on post id
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)

        comments = list(Comment.objects.filter(post=post).values())
        
        return JsonResponse({"comments": comments})
    except:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Post not found", "status": 404})
```

**index.js**

```
fetch(`/comments/${post_id}`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {

    // Appoints the number of comments in the Modal title
    document.querySelector("#exampleModalLongTitle").textContent = `${res.comments.length} Comments`;

    res.comments.forEach(comment => {
        
        modal_body = document.querySelector(".modal-body")

        b = document.createElement("b");
        span = document.createElement("span");
        br = document.createElement("br");
        span.classList.add("gray")

        b.textContent = comment.commented_by_id + " ";
        span.textContent = comment.comment;

        modal_body.appendChild(b);
        modal_body.appendChild(span);
        modal_body.appendChild(br);

    })
```

I can get the comment value using `comment.comment` in `js`. However, the problem arises when I convert the `comments` objects to `list.values` so now I lose the ability to get the user who posted the comment (`commented_by`)

**Any help to get the `comment` and `commented_by` values is appreciated.**

I also tried in **views.py:**

```
def load_comments(request, post_id):
    """Returns the comments to index.js"""
    try:
        # Filter comments returned based on post id
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)

        post_comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
        
        comments = []

        for comment in post_comments:
            comments.append({
                "comment": comment.comment,
                "commented_by": commented_by,
                })

        comments = serializers.serialize('json', comments)
        return HttpResponse(comments, content_type='application/json')
        
    except:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Post not found", "status": 404})
```

However when I try this, it outputs the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, the values() function for a ForeignKey field by default returns the id of the related object with the key formed by appending the name of the field with "_id". So in your case, you have your user ID under the key `commented_by_id`.

If by "loosing the ability to get the user who posted the comment" you mean other user info, like username, then you can pass the fields that you need to the values() function.

```
comments = list(Comment.objects
                       .filter(post=post)
                       .values("comment", 
                               "commented_by__username"
                               ))
```

will give a dict with the comment text and the user name (assuming that you have a `username` field in your User model.

Comment: This is what I was missing. Thanks for your generous help.

Answer (score 0):

1- you should use django_Rest_framework cuz it's very easy to work with api and show related field

2- use `Post.objects.get(id=post_id)` instead of pk

or you should skip this step by filter the comments depend on post id directly like`Comment.objects.all().filter(post_id=post_id)`